# module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'Tk' with python 3.5

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Launching my program i visualized this error: "module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'Tk'". So I changed the name of my program from "tkinter.py" to "tkinterrr.py" but I obtain that error as well. What can I do?

That's the code:

```
import tkinter as tk


LARGE_FONT = ("Verdana", 12)


class SeaofBTCapp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): #args all var, kwargs all dict

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = Tk.Frame(self) #frame hedge window

        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        frame = StartPage(container, self)

        self.frames[StartPage] = frame

        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew") #you specify all grid

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont] # key
        frame.tkraise()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Start Page", font=LARGE_FONT) #Label class label object
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

app = SeaofBTCapp()
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved... I didn't delete the old "tkinter.py" file from the directory!